# Conditional CSS in Ruby and Haml Table

Tags: css, ruby, haml

I have a list of items in a table. Some are true and some are false. Is there a way that the true elements can have one background colour whilst the false elements have another. I was considering writing a method in the application helper but I am not sure how is best to write this. So far all i have is

```
%td.success= person.success
```

This currently prints out true or false to the table but i would just like to add some background colour to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or why not something like this:

css

```
td.success { background-color: 'green' }
td.failure { background-color: 'red' }
```

then in the haml

```
%td{class: "#{person.success ? 'success' : 'failure'}"} = person.success
```

Or

```
- if person.success
  %td.success = person.success
- else
  %td.failure = person.success
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this within a helper file instead of within the haml?

Comment: @Em8 depends on what you mean by helper? Are we creating a view helper that will generate the DOM element? A boolean helper to just return the appropriate class `String`? maybe something like `def success_cell(val); haml_tag ("#{val ? 'td.success' : 'td.failure'}", val);end` and then you could just call `success_cell(person.success)`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider doing this with some JavaScript/jQuery when the page renders:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("td").each(function() {

        if ( $(this).html() === true ) {
             $(this).css("background", "blue");
        }
        else {
             $(this).css("background", "red");
        }

    }

}
```

With some more context to what your rendered HTML looks like, we can tweak this to get something more specific to your case.